# PayPal Rest List Payments

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am trying to pull a list of payments from my PayPal account. Here is a screenshot of the payments:

[image]

My request returns zero payments. I can confirm that my client id and secret are correct, since I can pull a list of invoices. What is wrong with my request?

GET https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment?count=10&start_index=5&start_date=2016-09-19T18:08:44Z&end_date=2016-10-19T18:08:44Z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct request would be:

```
https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment?count=10&start_index=5&start_time=2016-09-19T18:08:44Z&end_time=2016-10-19T18:08:44Z
```

I replaced *start_date* with *start_time* and *end_date* with *end_time*

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately, I am still unable to pull the payments. Do I need some special permissions on my account?

Comment: Please, clarify, you've been created payments with api previously? Paypal doc says: "Lists payments that were created by the create payment call".

Comment: @Ivnhal v1 of the payments API seems to be under deprecation. It is suggested to use v2 instead, but there is no list payments endpoint for v2, any ideas? https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v2/